# Access violation when reserve is called on a map

Tags: c++

I have a few `unordered_maps` that I use with custom allocators. In this case I use a rudimentary bump allocator that just simply linearly allocates new memory from an existing continiuos block.

But when I try and call reserve on these maps after a while, they throw an access violaton exception at the line within the std list file I'll show below in :

```
    _List_unchecked_const_iterator& operator++() noexcept {
        _Ptr = _Ptr->_Next;
        return *this;
    }
```

My allocator has enough memory left so I don't think it's because I am running out of memory.

Here's some self contained code that demonstrates it. Copy/paste and run it to see the issue.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

#define SEQ(type, val) sizeof(type) * val

struct ImpAllocator {
    virtual void* Allocate(size_t pSize) = 0;
    virtual void Free(void* pPtr) = 0;
};

struct SysAllocator : public ImpAllocator {
    void* Allocate(size_t pSize) override {
        return malloc(pSize);
    }

    void Free(void* pPtr) override {
        free(pPtr);
    }

};

template <class T>
class StdAllocatorWrapper {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<ImpAllocator> mInternalAllocator;

    using value_type = T;

    StdAllocatorWrapper() = default;
    StdAllocatorWrapper(std::shared_ptr<ImpAllocator> pInternalAllocator) :
        mInternalAllocator(pInternalAllocator)
    {}
    ~StdAllocatorWrapper() = default;
    StdAllocatorWrapper(const StdAllocatorWrapper<T>& pOther) = default;

    template<class U>
    StdAllocatorWrapper(const StdAllocatorWrapper<U>& pOther) {
        this->mInternalAllocator = pOther.mInternalAllocator;
    }

    value_type* allocate(size_t pNumberOfObjects) {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(mInternalAllocator->Allocate(SEQ(T, pNumberOfObjects)));
    }

    void deallocate(value_type* pPointer, size_t pNumberOfObjects) {
        mInternalAllocator->Free(pPointer);
    }
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(StdAllocatorWrapper<T> const& pL, StdAllocatorWrapper<U> const& pR) noexcept {
    return pL.mInternalAllocator == pR.mInternalAllocator;
}

template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(StdAllocatorWrapper<T> const& pL, StdAllocatorWrapper<U> const& pR) noexcept {
    return !(pL == pR);
}

template<typename T> using AllocWrapper = StdAllocatorWrapper<T>;
template<typename T, typename K> using Pair = std::pair<const T, K>;
template<typename T, typename K> using PairAllocWrapper = StdAllocatorWrapper<Pair<T, K>>;
template<typename T> using AllocatedVector = std::vector<T, AllocWrapper<T>>;
template<typename T> using AllocatedList = std::list<T, AllocWrapper<T>>;
template<typename T, typename K> using AllocatedUnorderedMap = std::unordered_map<T, K, std::hash<T>, std::equal_to<T>, PairAllocWrapper<T, K>>;

typedef unsigned char* MemBlock;

class BumpAllocator : public ImpAllocator {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<ImpAllocator> mInternalAllocator;
    size_t mSize;
    MemBlock mBlock;
    MemBlock mStart;;
    size_t mCurrent;

public:

    BumpAllocator(size_t pSize, std::shared_ptr<ImpAllocator> pInternalAllocator) :
        mInternalAllocator(pInternalAllocator),
        mSize(pSize),
        mCurrent(0) {
        mBlock = reinterpret_cast<MemBlock>(mInternalAllocator->Allocate(pSize));
        mStart = mBlock;
    }

    ~BumpAllocator() {
        mInternalAllocator->Free(mBlock);
    }

    void* Allocate(size_t pSize) override {
        printf("\n bump allocator wrapper requested: %d", pSize);
        if (mCurrent + pSize > mSize) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        MemBlock _return = mBlock + mCurrent;
        mCurrent += pSize;
        return _return;
    }

    void Free(void* pFre) override {

    }

    void Reset() {
        mCurrent = 0;
    }
};

struct Animation {

};

struct Texture {

};

struct TextureArrayIndex {
    //TexturePointer mTexture;
    unsigned int mIndex;
    std::shared_ptr<Texture> mTexture;
};

struct RenderOrder {
    float mDeltaTime;
    std::string mAnimationName;
    std::shared_ptr<Animation> mAnim;
};

using Textures = AllocatedUnorderedMap<int, TextureArrayIndex>;
using TexturesAllocWrapper = PairAllocWrapper<int, TextureArrayIndex>;
using RenderOrdersVector = AllocatedVector<RenderOrder>;
using RenderOrdersAllocWrapper = AllocWrapper<RenderOrder>;
using RenderBucket = AllocatedUnorderedMap<unsigned int, RenderOrdersVector>;
using RenderBuckets = AllocatedUnorderedMap<std::shared_ptr<Animation>, RenderBucket>;
using RenderBucketAllocWrapper = PairAllocWrapper<unsigned int, RenderOrdersVector>;
using RenderBucketsAllocWrapper = PairAllocWrapper<std::shared_ptr<Animation>, RenderBucket>;


struct Renderer {

    std::shared_ptr<BumpAllocator> mInternalAllocator;
    Textures mTextureArrayIndexMap;
    RenderBuckets mAnimationRenderBuckets;

    Renderer(std::shared_ptr<ImpAllocator> pAllocator) :
        mInternalAllocator(std::make_shared<BumpAllocator>(60000, pAllocator)),
        mTextureArrayIndexMap(Textures(TexturesAllocWrapper(mInternalAllocator))),
        mAnimationRenderBuckets(RenderBuckets(RenderBucketsAllocWrapper(mInternalAllocator))) 
    {}

    void Begin() {
        mTextureArrayIndexMap = Textures(TexturesAllocWrapper(mInternalAllocator));
        mTextureArrayIndexMap.reserve(2);
        mAnimationRenderBuckets = RenderBuckets(RenderBucketsAllocWrapper(mInternalAllocator));
        mAnimationRenderBuckets.reserve(1000);
    }

    void Render() {

    }

    void Flush() {
        mInternalAllocator->Reset();
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Renderer _renderer(std::make_shared<SysAllocator>());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        _renderer.Begin();
        _renderer.Flush();
    }
}
```

What's weird is that , the first 2 iterations work fine. But the third one fails... So reusing the memory works for the first 2 Begin--->Flush cycles but then the 3d one fail every time. So odd.

Comment: I've copied and pasted the code in godbolt (https://godbolt.org/z/xdMc9Yrf8).  It runs without throwing any errors.  I can't see any `std::unordered_maps` instantiations in the code, is that why?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy it only seems to crash with visual studio

Comment: Same with msvc.  Here : https://godbolt.org/z/K6xqzjEff

Comment: Sidenote: What you've implemented here is very similar to the functionality provided by `std::pmr` (`ImpAllocator` == [`std::pmr::memory_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource), `SysAllocator` == [`std::pmr::new_delete_resource()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new_delete_resource), `BumpAllocator` == [`std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource), `StdAllocatorWrapper` == [`std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator))

Comment: @MichaëlRoy the msvc is returning `3221225477` (`0xC0000005`)

Comment: If you do not throw on allocation error, and Allocate() fails, unordered_map will try to access memory from a null pointer, and this will generate a segmentation fault (error 0xC0000005).  That's expected.

Comment: There are unordered_maps . They are nested with 'using' phrases because they all use custom allocators so their definitions get too messy. Both Textures  and RenderBuckets are unordered_map s. @MichaëlRoy .

Comment: mTextureArrayIndexMap  and mAnimationRenderBuckets  are unordered maps.

Comment: @OmerOzer  There is no access to your maps in the code given, other than allocating. By that, I mean no insertion, no deletion, and no access to iterators, where you claim your original error happens.  The requirement for an allocator to throw on error is MANDATORY for all STL containers, that includes std::vector, std::list and  std::unordered_map.  There is no way to work around that, save for writing your own containers (as is done when code with no exception is a VITAL requirement) . Have you tried placing breakpoints in your allocators as suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes I tried putting breaking points. The bac alloc case never gets triggered. Also my original claim as you can see in the title is that when I 'reserve' on a map , the error fires. And that is what is happening on my end sadly. Not when I do any kind of insertion or deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally. The problem was that inside the Begin method, I am initializing the maps again. This happens after Reset is called. Meaning the memory allocation takes place from the beginning. This would be fine. However, at this time. Both the new maps and the old ones exist at the same time and they overlap fully on the same memory. This also would be fine but then when the new map is assigned to the old one, the destructor of the old one is called and it frees the memory that is being used by the newly instantiated maps.

I fixed the issue by making the maps pointers ( `std::unordered_map*` ) . So now my map "reinstantiation" is as follows `mTextureArrayIndexMap = new Textures(...)` . So the destructor of the old map is not called. And this is perfectly fine since the whole thing is being allocated on a bump memory that is reset.

The code runs smoothly now with no issues!

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce the error with the code given...  But the code does not use `std::unordered_map`, so the error must come from there.

First issue. In your allocators:

```
void* SysAllocator::Allocate(size_t pSize) override {
    return malloc(pSize);   // allocator returns NULL on error.
  
}

void* BumpAllocator::Allocate(size_t pSize) override {
    printf("\n bump allocator wrapper requested: %d", pSize);
    if (mCurrent + pSize > mSize) {
        return nullptr;     // allocator returns NULL on error.
    }
    MemBlock _return = mBlock + mCurrent;
    mCurrent += pSize;
    return _return;
}
```

Your custom allocators return NULL on error, but STL containers expect their allocators to throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception on error.  That's **mandatory**.

You should change your allocators:

```
void* SysAllocator::Allocate(size_t pSize) override {
    void* p = malloc(pSize);
    if (!p)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    return p;
}

void* BumpAllocator::Allocate(size_t pSize) override {
    printf("\n bump allocator wrapper requested: %d", pSize);
    if (mCurrent + pSize > mSize)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    MemBlock _return = mBlock + mCurrent;
    mCurrent += pSize;
    return _return;
}
```

This will not solve your problem, but the point of error will have moved to the time of allocation.

I think your problem comes from a lack of memory. std::unordered_map uses hash buckets, and these could very likely use more memory than you anticipated.  To investigate, set breakpoints on the `throw` lines in your `Allocate()` functions to catch the error right when it happens.

Comment: mTextureArrayIndexMap and mAnimationRenderBuckets are unordered maps. I tried throwing bac alloc instead of returning null. It actually made no difference. I get the same error. And the bac alloc never even fires. There is still plenty of memory left I think so it never gets to that line.

Comment: There is plenty of memory left, but how much memory do you reserve?  You are constrained to the memory you initially allocate for your allocator.  This memory cannot grow.  The code you have given in your question works.  This means the error is somewhere else, and no one around here has the mystic powers required to guess where that error is without seeing the code.

Comment: Did you try running it on visual studio? It's weird that I'm having the issue only.  Also I am initially allocating 60000 bytes for the whole thing.

Comment: I'm on linux at the moment, can't do.  But godbolt uses the msvc compiler.  There is nowhere in the code where you access std::list<>::operator++(), so I suspect you are not running the code as posted.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the issue mentioned by Michael Roy, there is another bug here

```
void Reset() {
    mCurrent = 0;
}
```

This method, which is called indirectly from your main, means that further allocations will reuse already allocated memory. This is the immediate cause of the crash in the code you posted.

If you comment out the line `mCurrent = 0;` then you do actually run out of memory and you get the null pointer bug explained by Michael Roy in the other answer.

Tested with MSVC (since that seems to be significant).

Comment: This isn't a bug. It's intended behaivor. I want to reuse already allocated memory. Immediately after Reset is called, maps are reinstantiated. My goal is to get them to reuse existing memory from 0 again.

Comment: @OmerOzer You cannot guarantee that after reset is called that the already allocated memory will not be needed again. And in fact, in this standard library implementation, that is what happens.

Comment: Could you elaborate? In this case, the bump memory only ever used by the two maps I have. And after I call reset, I reinstantiate them so the older maps will not longer be using any memory. Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @OmerOzer You don't 'reinstantiate' the maps, you create new ones and assign them to the old. Creating new maps involves allocating memory, and this reuses already allocated memory (plus the reserve that happens on the texture map happens before the animation map has been assigned to).